# Segmentation fault (error) in a multi threaded app in PyQt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I have a multi thread application in python for data image post-processing. The main thread is running in a `while` loop while the secondary thread is in charge of frame capturing and plotting. The problem is stopping the secondary thread and restarting it, which is when the segmentation failure occurs.

That's the code:

```
def run(self):
    for n_iteration in range(2):
        for r in range(10):
            for c in range(10):
                # Stop For nested
                if self.loopCal == True:
                    self.threadStp_cal = True
                    break
                else:
                    frame1D = self.tis.cameraFrame()
                    qImg = QtGui.QImage(frame1D, frame1D.shape[1], frame1D.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
                    image_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)
                    self.signalCal_Camera.emit(image_pixmap)
            # Second break loop
            if self.loopCal == True:
                break
        # Final break loop
        if self.loopCal == True:
            self.threadStopped_cal.emit(self.threadStp_cal)
            self.threadStp_cal = False
            break
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide your code with examples for input & output

Comment: I put the critical part of the code that I think could be problematic, as it is in charge of emitted and received signals.

Comment: @Moma please provide a [mre]. For now, do not use QPixmap from another thread since it is not thread safe, instead it emits the QImage, and just converts the QImage to QPixmap in the main thread.